# Send/Receive on two numbers

Tags: iphone

How can I receive my husbands text messages without him receiving mine? Does it matter is he has the 4s and I have the 5c?

Answer (score 1):

Cell carriers don't deliver two SMS to one phone as far as I've heard.

You could sign your husband into iMessage on your phone and presumably it would receive both your SMS and his iMessage, but it is likely you can't accomplish the mix you seek with iOS.